# Replacing a pattern with a string

Tags: bash, string

Suppose we declare

```
test="/this/isjust/atestvariable/for/stringoperation"
```

and we want to replace each instance of '/' with the colon ':'.

Then, I think this command should work:

```
echo ${test//\/:}
```

(as `${variable//pattern/string}` replaces all matches of the pattern with the specified string )

But, on running echo `${test//\/:}`, I get the output as

```
/this/isjust/atestvariable/for/stringoperation
```

Where I could be going wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

escape slash with backslash

```
echo ${test//\//:}
```

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
${test//\/:}
```

would replace all instances (since double-slash `//` in the start) of `/:` with nothing (no second unescaped slash).

This:

```
${test/\//:}
```

Would replace the *first* instance (since a single slash as separator) of `/` (which was escaped) with `:`.

And this:

```
${test//\//:}
```

Should replace all matches of `/` with a `:`.

Example:

```
$ test="/this/isjust/atestvariable/:for/:stringoperation"
$ echo ${test//\/:}
/this/isjust/atestvariableforstringoperation
$ echo ${test/\//:}
:this/isjust/atestvariable/:for/:stringoperation
$ echo ${test//\//:}
:this:isjust:atestvariable::for::stringoperation
```